# what is the difference between lambda function and std::function in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

In my case, i defined a function in two different ways, fun1 is a lambda function, func2 is a regular std function,but the lambda one doesn't work with variadic arguments template funcction(vat_function).

the code below shows the problem:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <typename... ParamTypes>
void vat_function(std::function<void(ParamTypes...)>,ParamTypes... parames)
{//this is a variadic arguments template function
};

void faa_function(std::function<void(bool,int)>,bool b,int i)
{//this is a std::function as parameter function
};

int main() 
{
    auto func1 = [](bool,int)->void
    {   
    };
    std::function<void(bool,int)> func2 = [](bool,int)->void
    {   
    };

    bool b=false;
    int i=0;
    vat_function<bool,int>(func1,b,i);//only this one doesn't work
    vat_function<bool,int>(func2,b,i);//OK

    faa_function(func1,b,i);//OK
    faa_function(func2,b,i);//OK
}
```

vat_function(func1,b,i) doesn't work, why faa_function(func1,b,i) works?

Comment: Every lambda-expression creates a unique type and yields an object of that type (the closure-type). As this type is unrelated to `std::function`, type deduction fails for `vat_function`. So maybe you could say *they're both function object types, but otherwise unrelated*. A `std::function` is a polymorphic function wrapper, whereas a lambda object always refers to one specific function.

Comment: The `faa_function` example works because this lambda can be converted to a `std::function<void(bool,int)>` via a conversion-ctor of `std::function`, and no type deduction is involved in selecting an overload of `faa_function`.